# Inserting prop into Jest test for react component - receiving 'Cannot read property 'map' of undefined' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am testing a React component and receiving an error due to a prop. How do I properly insert the prop into the test? Is this the correct route to take?

```
//Test File

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import List from './List';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

describe('List Component', () => {
    it('renders to DOM', () => {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        ReactDOM.render(<List />, div);
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
    });

    it('renders UI as expected', () => {
        const tree = renderer  
            .create(<List/>)
            .toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
})

//Component

import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card';
import './List.css';

function List(props) {
    return (
        <section className='List'>
            <header className='List-header'>
                <h2>{props.header}</h2>
            </header>
            <div className="List-cards">
                {props.cards.map((card) =>
                    <Card
                        key={card.id}
                        title={card.title}
                        content={card.content}
                    />
                )}

                <button type="button" className="List-add-button">
                    + Add Random Card
                </button>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}

export default List;



● List Component › renders to DOM

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

      10 |             </header>
      11 |             <div className="List-cards">
    > 12 |                 {props.cards.map((card) =>
         |                              ^
      13 |                     <Card
      14 |                         key={card.id}
      15 |                         title={card.title}
```

I have tried to adding the prop in different spots with fail

I am expecting the tests to pass without fail but only receive a failing test due to prop

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `List` component uses `header` and `cards` props.

You will need to provide those props when rendering `List` during your tests:

```
const props = {  // <= create the mock props
  header: 'the header',
  cards: [
    {
      id: 'id1',
      title: 'title 1',
      content: 'content 1'
    },
    {
      id: 'id2',
      title: 'title 2',
      content: 'content 2'
    }
  ]
}
ReactDOM.render(<List {...props} />, div);  // <= pass the mock props to the List component
```